# Attempting to draw in a JPanel from a SwingWorker done() method does nothing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d, swingworker

I'm trying to paint a JPanel using Graphics2D, and I'd like the drawing to happen in a SwingWorker's `done()` method, after some math in `doInBackGround()`, but this seems to not draw anything?

What is wrong in my code?

```
class MyJanel extends JPanel  {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        MyExecutor worker = new MyExecutor(g2);
        worker.execute();
    }

    class MyExecutor extends SwingWorker<Void,Void> { 

        Graphics2D gRef;
        int result;

        public MyExecutor(Graphics2D g2){
            gRef = g2;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() {
            result = 100+100;
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            gRef.drawLine(20, 20, result, result);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Never keep a reference to a Graphics object (unless you create the Graphics yourself). If you want to trigger `paintComponent()`, invoke `repaint()`. Also, never put stateful code in `paintComponent()` because you cannot determine when and how many times it will be invoked.

Comment: `Never keep a reference to a Graphics object (unless you create the Graphics yourself)` Source please? Thanks

Comment: I don't have any source, it's just experience that tells me that when you do that, you always run into problems. And when you think about it, it's very logical.

Answer (score 3):

The paintComponent() method is only for painting! Get rid of the SwingWorker code from the paintComponent() method.

If you want to paint a component then the done() method should invoke a property on the component. For example in your case you are attempting to draw a line, so the code in your paintComponent method might look like:

```
super.paintComponent(g);

if (drawLine)
    g.drawLine(...);
```

Then you would create a method like:

```
public void setDrawLine(Boolean drawLine)
{
    this.drawLine = drawLine;
    repaint();
}
```

So in the done() method you simply invoke `setDrawLine(true)` on your component.

Also, whenever you do custom painting you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the dimension of the component so the layout manager can use this information, otherwise the size will be (0, 0) and there will be nothing to paint. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) for more information and working examples.

Maybe you also need a separate method to start the SwingWorker in your component.

Edit:

I changed your code:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(final Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawLine(10, 0, 10, 100);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            g2.drawLine(100, 0, 100, 100);
        }
    });
}
```

Which also doesn't work. I'm guessing that since the code is added to the end of the EDT, that when it executes the Graphics objects has already been disposed.

Comment: `The paintComponent() method is only for painting! Get rid of the SwingWorker code from the paintComponent() method.` I don't think there is something bad with it? In the end it's just a way to trigger some drawing, in this particular case as a result of a SwingWorker, so what's wrong with it being called there?

Comment: I do have `getPreferredSize()` in my code, only I just did not include in the example here, updated the code with it.

Comment: @jj_, A painting method is for painting only. Swing will invoke the painting methods when it determines painting needs to be done. You should not be invoking any external functions not related directly to painting.

Comment: I want to say you are right, but of all the many examples and code I see online, I see none going with your nothing-except-drawing-code-in-paintComponent() purist theory. Could you please provide source for your information? Thanks

Comment: @jj_ There is a lot of very poor examples on the Web. Many people have only little knowledge of AWT/Swing internals and don't use it in its best way. The best source of info is probably the Oracle tutorials and documentation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks and I am more enclined to believe that these guys know what they talk about that some random examples picked up on the web.

Comment: @jj_, See edit. There is no one source of information. In addition to the above it is based on experiences of many people in the forums and based on questions like this.